# Why can't I open/close multiple divs with animate?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm experiencing a couple of problems with my code.

Whats expected to happen: 
- User clicks 'Open' = Slide show 'content'.
- User clicks 'Open' again = hide 'content'.

I was hoping this would work for multiple instances. (it somewhat moves with one instance) But right now I can't get to ....

1.) Open/Close 
and 2.) Work with multiple instances.

What am I doing wrong? :\

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_open_button").click(function(){
        var layer = $("#id_faded_layer");
        var hiddenButtons = $('#id_open');
        layer.animate({
            bottom: 0,
            height: '7em',
            top: '-97px'
        });
        hiddenButtons.css('display','block');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7kd89h7r/3/) to show what I'm working with.

Thank you in advance, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why are you setting the bottom to 0? Explicitly setting top and bottom and then trying to set the height doesn't make much sense, as they are more or less mutually exclusive.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Look into using classes if you need to repeat identifiers.

Comment: @JDB thank you for spotting that. i'll be sure to fix :)

Comment: It looks like your click function isn't firing... Try to isolate each issue and attack it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you seem to not quite understand how HTML layout works. You've restricted the container height to 100px (with overflow "hidden"), then display the "Open" button using absolute positioning in such a way that it's completely covering the "drawer" that's supposed to be opening. You are also animating the height, top and bottom properties, but explicitly setting the top and bottom doesn't make sense if you are also going to explicitly set the height. You've also set the top of the drawer to -97px and the height to 7em (which is almost certainly less than 97px), so it's rendered completely outside of the div (above and beyond where it can be seen).

You've seriously over-complicated this design. I suggest you start over again with something much, much simpler.

I've rewritten some of the HTML/CSS and got it working just fine, although I don't know what your ultimate goal is.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id_open_button").click(function(){
  var layer = $("#id_faded_layer");
  var hiddenButtons = $('#id_open_hidden');
  layer.animate({
   height: '200px'
        });
        hiddenButtons.css('display','block');
 });
});
```

```css
.faded {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(21, 20, 20, 0.37) 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(21, 20, 20, 0.37) 100% );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(21, 20, 20, 0.37) 100% );
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(21, 20, 20, 0.37) 100% );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(21, 20, 20, 0.37) 100% );
}

.prompt{
    top: 0; 
    padding: 8px; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="">
    <div class="columns three image">
        <div class="faded" id="id_faded_layer">
            <div id="id_open">
                <a>Show content</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prompt">
            <a id="id_open_button" style="">Open</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="columns three image">
        <div class="faded" id="id_faded_layer">
            <div id="id_open">
                <a>Show content</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prompt">
            <a id="id_open_button" style="">Open</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I just wanted to thank you for your post. I appreciate you taking the time to help me. It addresses my main problems, but one thing I still have to deal with is the unique identifiers. Your post doesn't address that. I'll be headed back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Modelesq - Repeated IDs were not your only or even the major issue. Even with unique IDs, your design wouldn't work.